# How to use cockroachdb column families with liquidbase

Tags: liquibase, cockroachdb, column-family

In order to manage column updates more effectively cockroach db has a family feature: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/column-families.html

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    last_accessed TIMESTAMP,
    data BYTES,
    FAMILY f1 (id, last_accessed),
    FAMILY f2 (data)
);
```

Is there any to describe liquibase script to create table with two or more families?

Something like

```
changes:
  - createTable:
      tableName: test
      columns:
        - column:
            constraints:
              primaryKey: true
              primaryKeyName: pk_id
            name: id
            type: INT
        - column:
            name: last_accessed 
            type: TIMESTAMP
        - column:
            name: data
            type: bytes
# not real liquibase yaml just question
      families:
        - family:
            name: f1
            columns:
            - id
            - last_accessed
        - family:
            name: f2
            columns:
            - data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [SQL changeset](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/sql-format.html?Highlight=formatted%20changelog) or [SQL change types](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/sql.html).